# how to extract WCF REST services server response by POST method in android client

Tags: android, wcf

how to extract WCF REST services server response by POST method in android client. I have done encryption on string , then send it to server, facing problem..

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
                jObject.put("jsonString", eJSON);
                jObject.put("key", cryptKey);

                Log.i("jason Object", jObject.toString());
                post.setHeader("json", jObject.toString());
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jObject.toString());
                se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                        "application/json"));
                post.setEntity(se);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is code to get the exact response.

```
HttpEntity responseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
        Log.d(TAG, "response.getEntity() = " + getResponse.getEntity());
        String HTTP_response = null;
        try {
            HTTP_response = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);
            Log.i(TAG, "Jsontext = " + HTTP_response);
        } catch (ParseException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            String Res = response.getEntity().toString();
            Log.i("GetEntity",Res);
```

but only element getting... require expert help.